# How to print RowMatrix in Scala/Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix, printing, parallel-processing

How can I view/print to screen a small `RowMatrix` in Scala?

```
val A = new RowMatrix(sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    Vectors.dense(1, 2, 3),
    Vectors.dense(4, 5, 6))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it's just

```
A.rows.collect
```

FYI: Beware of the matrix size.